# Syntax of union of several sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, set, set-union

I would like to understand why is this a valid syntax:

```
common = (set(classes['Biology']) & set(classes['Math']) & set(classes['PE']) & set(classes['Social Sciences']) & set(classes['Chemistry']))
```

but not this:

```
common = set(classes['Biology']) & set(classes['Math']) & set(classes['PE'] & set(classes['Social Sciences']) & set(classes['Chemistry'])
```

TL;DR

Why is there a need to put all the unions into normal braces

> ()

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is invalid because it's missing a close paren on `set(classes['PE']`. You don't need the outer parentheses, you just need to close the inner ones correctly.

Side-note: Performance-wise, you'd likely save a little by only explicitly converting the first item to a `set`, then using the `intersection` (which takes an arbitrary number of iterable arguments) to do the rest of the work in a single Python function call:

```
common = set(classes['Biology']).intersection(classes['Math'], classes['PE'], classes['Social Sciences'], classes['Chemistry'])
```

Comment: Oh my god. I guess I have to be tired already. I've red those 2 codes like 5 times and I've seen them the same except outer braces... I've just copied it from a text file so syntax highlight wasn't available...

Comment: @boldi: Suggestion: Always use a syntax highlighting text editor. Even on Windows, lightweight stuff like Notepad++ supports syntax highlighting without needing to go to full fledged IDEs. Saves a *lot* of headaches. On Linux, with minor configuration, you likely have at least three syntax highlighting editors available, if not more. :-)

Comment: Yes. I am aware of the benefits of syntax highlight. This was just a exceptional situation, because I was on a PC that wasn't mine and wanted to do some Python learning in the meantime.